# Force xfce4-power-manager to suspend

Tags: xfce, power-management, suspend

I would like my power button to suspend - no questions asked.

xfce4-power-manager would like my power button to suspend - but only after I have been asked:

> An application is currently disabling the automatic sleep. Doing this action now may damage the working state of this application.

It seems to be caused by having a YouTube video on pause. And I really could not care less. The surprising part is that if I close my lid, then xfce4-power-manager *does* understand that it should suspend no questions asked.

So is there a way I can make xfce4-power-manager understand that when I press the power button, I simply want the same behaviour as if I closed the lid?

In Power manager settings both 'When power button is pressed' and 'When laptop lid is closed' are set to 'Suspend'.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
git clone git://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager
```

edit xfce4-power-manager/src/xfpm-power.c

find and comment lines:

```
if(power->priv->inhibited && force == FALSE) {
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    gboolean ret;

    dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL,
            GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
            GTK_MESSAGE_QUESTION,
            GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO,
            _("An application is currently disabling the automatic sleep. "
                "Doing this action now may damage the working state of this application.\n"
                "Are you sure you want to hibernate the system?"));
    ret = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);


    if(!ret || ret == GTK_RESPONSE_NO)
        return;
}
```

run:

```
cd xfce4-power-manager
sh autogen.sh
make
```

copy:

```
cp -pf src/xfce4-pm-helper /usr/bin
cp -pf src/xfce4-power-manager /usr/bin
cp -pf src/xfpm-power-backlight-helper /usr/bin
```

to /usr/bin or where xfce4-power-manager is

logout and login.